# using Auth0 and Azure Identity provider for Ionic angular application

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, .net-core

Hi I need some architectural help. I am building a mobile app in ionic angular. I was looking to sign up user using Auth0 social identity provider. Once the users are authenticated, I wanted to make api calls hosted in Azure in a app service by passing access token issued by Microsoft identity provider from the mobile app. How do I achieve this ? making the api call and passing the access token in the header ?

Comment: You should use official SDK to implement it. Please check https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a backend API that is authorized via auth0, as well as your ionic angular app, the following link will assist in going about this.

https://auth0.com/blog/complete-guide-to-angular-user-authentication/